# Put checkbox list in resize-able area

Tags: php, html, css

I have the code below that populates a list of selectable items from the DB. I am wondering how I would go about putting this list in a resize-able area, something like textarea or something.

I tried putting into a textarea, but then it just outputs the input type html code into a text area.

```php
$link=mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass) 
    or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db, $link) 
    or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

$query="SELECT software_id, software_name FROM software";
$result=mysql_query($query) 
    or die ("Query to get data from Profiles Table failed: ".mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $software_id=$row["software_id"];
    $software_name=$row["software_name"];

    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$software_id' value='$software_name'>$software_name<br />";

}
```

Comment: Umm this looks like a design problem. You need to make use of CSS to wrap them in a re-sizeable container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="resize:both; overflow:scroll; width:300px; height:300px; border:1px solid black">
<td>php data</td>
</div>
```

@Chris Thank you, it worked like a charm :)